# Is it reasonable to use scrollview for a limited list in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I have a short list of persons, they won't be over  25. I have read about the better performance of the Flatlist for long lists, So is ScrollView useless now?  If so, Why It's Not deprecated? I am wondering which one is better for a short list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, `ScrollView` is generally best for managing assorted components, and `FlatList` is better for displaying data of the same type.

If you have a variety of components (e.g., some kind of input form with text, combo boxes, checkboxes, etc), all you'd need to do is surround those components with a `ScrollView` to prevent them from extending beyond the screen limits.  (there's issues with managing the keyboard for text items, but that's another topic)

`FlatList`, on the other hand, takes data and render attributes and can efficiently display hundreds of data items (usually of the same type).

Since you're just displaying data, `FlatList` is probably the better choice.